# Solving System of ODEs $ \frac{d}{dt}u(t)=v(t)^p $ and $ \frac{d}{dt}v(t)=u(t)^q $

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a simple ODE system but I cannot solve :

$$
\frac{d}{dt}u(t)=v(t)^p
$$
and 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}v(t)=u(t)^q
$$

Here $p>1\;,\,q>1$. And we solve ODEs on $[0\,,\,\infty)$ with initial conditions $u(0)=K_1\;,\;v(0)=K_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You can use this way to solve. Clearly
$$ \frac{du}{dv}=\frac{v^p}{u^q} $$
from which we have
$$ u^qdu=v^pdv. $$
This is a separable DE and you can solve.

Comment: Thanks, but I ended up in a complicated integral.