# integrate $\int_a^b\frac{dx}{\left (x^{p+1}-C\right)^q}$

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Can anyone come up with the general formulae to integrate above integral. You can take the power of $x$,i.e. $p+1>2$ and $q>1$ if it facilitates.

Regards,

Harish

Comment: Where does the $q$ go?

Comment: @Chinny84 I just edited my post please see.

Answer (score 0):

For $a=0,~b\to\infty,$ and $q\in\mathbb N,~$ let $~I(C)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x^{^{\Large p+1}}-C}.~$ Then the original integral can be

easily written as $I^{^{\LARGE(q-1)}}(C)$, times a constant depending on *q*. At the same time, using the fact

that $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{k-1}}{1-x^n}~dx~=~\frac\pi n~\cot\bigg(k~\frac\pi n\bigg)~$ — see [Cauchy principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) — we can immediately

conclude that $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{k-1}}{a^n-x^n}~dx~=~\frac\pi n~\cot\bigg(k~\frac\pi n\bigg)~a^{k-n},~$ by means of the simple substitution

$x=at.~$ Now let $k=1,~$ $~n=p+1,~$ and $~C=a^n=a^{p+1}$. Can you take it from here ? ;-$)$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I couldn't justify your claim that, original integral can bee written as $I(C)^{(q-1)}$. Moreover I was seeking for integral with $a\neq 0$. Letting $b\rightarrow \infty$ is not a problem. Being precise, I am actually trying to guess the blow up time for the solution for ODE in this question..http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185652/solving-system-of-odes-fracddtut-vtp-and-fracddtvt-utq

Comment: @Harish: Then I am afraid that the general solution to this problem does not possess a nice closed form solution, except the one resulting from partial fraction decomposition. As for your other concern, what happens when we differentiate $\dfrac1{x^n+C}$ with regard to *C* ?

Comment: I thought you are raising $I$ by power $q-1$. (instead of differentiating $q-1$ times) Thanks. As it may turn out useful in other context. @Lucian